# Visual Studio Remote Debugging on XP Embedded - tried everything, please help!

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, embedded, connect

I need to debug some C# code on a remote machine running **XP Embedded**. I did remote debugging on several occasions on different Windows operating systems and all worked well, but I think that the XP Embedded OS is missing something.

I'm popping my brains out in the last couple of days, reading and trying stuff, but nothing seems to work. So if you have been in the same situation and found a solution, please help. Here is what I did up to now:

1. Successfully established a remote debugging connection to an **XP Professional** environment, so I know that there's nothing wrong with my remote configuration.
2. Started the **same services** on the Embedded environment that are running on the Professional environment.
3. Configured **DCOM permissions**, **firewall**, **local users** with same name and passwords on both local and remote machines. Gave local users **administrator** rights.
4. Started msvsmon.exe both as an application and as a service, under the local user account, wich also has log on as a service rights.
5. Triple-checked that there is **no other firewall** between the machines that could drop remote debugging packets.

If I use the No authentication (native only) mode on the Embedded machine, the remote debugging works and I can see the processes. Otherwise, I get an error: 
Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named '[NAME]'. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may
be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may
be preventing communication to the remote computer.  Please see
Help for assistance.

Thank you for the time you took to read this and any suggestion may help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use WireShark to capture the data going to the remote XP embedded device?  If you get a TCP acknowledgement, at least you'll know it's not a firewall problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I've checked that. No firewall related issue. Also, in No authentication (native only) mode I can connect and the processes show up. Because of lack of time I installed Visual Studio and debugged directly on the machine, but I would still like to do it remotely. So if you have any other ideas, please share and I will try them out and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to start msvsmon.exe with admistrator rights ? Maybe that is the issue, a post by John Robbins explains it : http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/15/vs-remote-debugging-across-workgroups-or-domains.aspx.